# Хороший учебник по C/C++ для начинающих

Tags: c, книги

Где найти хороший учебник по C/C++ для начинающих. Желательно, чтоб новичёк понял (я ничего не знаю о C) и чтоб от простого к профессиональному. И не сборник примеров кодов, а именно учебник. И желательно на русском.

Comment: Каждому свое.
Посмотри в ответах...
Много таких вопросов

Comment: Языка C/C++ не существует. Либо C, либо C++.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. C и С++ - несколько разные языки, и учебники по ним разные.
2. Здесь эта тема появлялась уже множество раз. Поищите по форуму.

Но все же еще раз напишу. Книг действительно очень много. Но начинать нужно не с книг типа "Visual C++...", "C++ Builder...", т.е без привязки к конкретной среде, компилятору или платформе. Сначала нужно выучить общие принципы языка.

Сам и С, и С++ начинал учить по книгам Стивена Праты "Язык программирования С" и "Язык программирования С++". Написаны хорошим языком, для абсолютных новичков не только в С, но и в программировании вообще, много примеров, много упражнений. По С++ многие хвалят книги Шилдта. Книгу Страуструпа лучше читать попозже. По С классическая книга Кернигана и Ритчи, но я считаю, что с нее лучше не начинать, особенно новичку. Да и С язык довольно простой, в одной книге его можно изложить практически полностью (имею в виду стандартный язык). Указанных 2 книг вполне хватит.

Comment: Уже читаю в этой книге про String и массивы char с '\0' Спасибо замечательная книга!!!!Как раз для меня! И откуда учитель физики (Стивен Парта) столько знает? :)

Answer (score 1):

Из книг по С++ в среде Visual Studio советую очень книги Айвора Хортона.
Самая новая (Visual C++ 2010) не имеется в электронном варианте на русском (во всяком случае я не находил), так что если плохо с английским, то можете почитать Айвор Хортон - Visual C++ 2005, она переведена, как по мне - написана достаточно просто и при этом очень хорошо. Сразу учит и С++ и чем отличается среда разработки от других и разница между "Native" C++ и C++/CLI (я имею введу тот, что запускается под CLR), начинает с самых основ и с середины книги уже начинает про концепции программирования под Windows, MFC, и т.п.

Comment: C++\CLI мало кому нужен, будет только голову забивать новичку. На MFC тоже никто почти программы не пишет.

Comment: Верно, С++/CLI зачастую если и используется, то разве что для того, чтобы связывать управляемый код на C# и неуправляемыми старыми модулями С++. Однако не в этом дело, так или иначе оно идет не отдельными главами, а после каждой главы просто приводятся аналоги C++/CLI, это просто позволит ему разбираться в разных реализациях С++ и что такое управляемый код, в общем, как минимум, теория какая-то. MFC идет уже после середины книги, до этого 10 глав о нем речи не идет, к тому же MFC - как это на нем никто ничего не пишет? Во-первых: если учиться в ВУЗе, то там нужно будет иногда использовать.

Comment: , во-вторых: на вакансии C++ Developer не редко в необходимых навыках есть MFC.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше начать с классической книги [The C Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language), [ruwiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A1%D0%B8_(%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0)) написанной создателями языка. В ней подробно и обстоятельно объясняются все детали языка.

На C++ лучше посмотреть уже после досконального освоения Си. (А лучше не смотреть вовсе)

Comment: Vladimir VG Цитата:"На C++ лучше посмотреть уже после доскАнального освоения Си. (А лучше не смотреть вовсе)". Конец цитаты.  Правильно же - 
"доскОнального" - Как же вы пишете на Си или C++, не освоив даже родной язык?! Вот из-за этого спутники и падают!!! И эти ошибки сплошь и рядом у программеров!!!

Comment: а по теме? =/

Comment: Начинать с K&R? Лучше уж сразу с ассемблера )))

Comment: Почему? K&R вполне доступная книга.

Comment: Но не как первый учебник, особенно for absolute beginners

Comment: Ну дык в стартовом посте говорится о том что человек новичёк в именно Си. Вполне возможно он имеет опыт программирования на других языках, и тогда K&R -- то что доктор прописал.

Answer (score -1):

Тема не нова. Советовать что-то достаточно сложно, так как книг по С++ очень много. Посмотрите:

- Язык программирования С++
- Программирование на C++/C# в Visual Studio .NET 2003
- C++ и Pascal в Kylix 3. Разработка интернет-приложений и СУБД
- Технологии программирования C++
- Освой самостоятельно C++ за 21 день
- C++. Бархатный путь
- Программирование на C++
- C++ Solutions: Companion to the C++ Programming Language

Comment: >•Программирование на C++/C# в Visual Studio .NET 2003
 •C++ и Pascal в Kylix 3. Разработка интернет-приложений и СУБД

 Это что-то не то. Тут ещё паскаль мешается, к тому же, интернет-приложения и СУБД ему ещё рано писать. Не уверен, что это его интересует.

 А к Visual Studio тоже его не надо привязывать, особенно, что тут ещё C# будет отвлекать.

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю, C нет особого смысла изучать, если собираешься писать только на C++. Изучай сразу C++, так как, изучая C, ты приобретёшь вредные привычки, типа использования макросов, без которых в C++ можно обойтись и которые нежелательно в нём использовать, небезопасного эллипсиса, и объявления переменных в начале функции(их лучше объявлять перед самым использованием, о чём подробно пишет Макконелл в книге "Совершенный код").

Я начинал с книги "Освой C++ за 24 часа", выполняя все упражнения и отвечая на все вопросы. Вроде там описано всё достаточно понятно. Даже не знаю, почему к ней несерьёзно относятся. Из-за немного вызывающего названия что ли? Она хорошо структурирована, есть упражнения и вопросы в конце главы. Я достаточно быстро изучил C++(не на 100%, что практически невозможно, и без паттернов, естественно), умел писать простые программы. По мере написания своего игрового движка подсматривал в книгах то, что забыл.

Нужна не только теория, но и практика. Придумай себе какой-то проект и пиши его, параллельно изучая язык. Если ты просто прочитаешь книгу и ничего не напишешь, то скоро забудешь.

Это будет первый этап изучения. Следующим этапом будет изучением библиотеки, на которой ты будешь что-то реализовывать. Это может быть OpenGL, DirectX, WinAPI, игровой движок или ещё что-то, в зависимости от того, что ты хочешь сделать. Если тебя устроит консольное окно, то этот этап можно пропустить. Например, при изучении языка я не понимал, зачем нужны указатели. Используя разные библиотеки я понял, что без них не обойтись.

Наконец, нужно ещё прочитать множество книг, в которых говорится, как повысить эффективность написания программ и читабельность кода.

P. S. Почему минус? Не понравилось "C нет особого смысла изучать"? В книгах по C++ даже об этом пишут. А на вопрос я вроде ответил. Ну вот, ещё один минус поставили. Аргументируйте, почему. Может быть вы меня неправильно поняли? Я переформулировал ответ попонятнее.

Comment: Руки прочь от С )))

Comment: Все зависит от того имеет ли ТС опыт в программирывании, если нет я думаю что, все-же, стоит начать именно с С т.к. С++, мягко говоря, не простой :)

Comment: Тоже правильно. Вообще, думаю, ООП лучше с жабы начинать. Оно там много проще реализована. Потом и к С++ перейти.

Comment: C это отличный макроассемблер с типами, а C++ не слишком удачный препроцессор (с набором библиотек) к нему.

Каждому языку своя область применения.

Comment: Ну, это ты, братец, загнул.

Comment: >Все зависит от того имеет ли ТС опыт в программирывании, если нет я думаю что, все-же, стоит начать именно с С т.к. С++, мягко говоря, не простой :)

 А потом захочет перейти на C++, а будет писать в стиле С. Приобретёт всякие привычки задавать константы при помощи #define, использовать эллипсис (printf, scanf) вместо безопасных аналогов и т. д. Лучше уж сразу учить C++ или выбрать язык полегче, C#, например.

Comment: Руки геть вiд Ci!

Лимит комментариев исчерпан ((((((

Comment: >Руки геть вiд Ci!
Cオフハンズ!

Comment: >изучая C, ты приобретёшь вредные привычки, типа использования макросов
Вредные привычки - это не особенность языка Си, это особенность мышления человека. Просто нужно помнить что когда программируешь на си, нужно программировать на си, а когда на с++ - на с++, а не на "приплюснутом" си :)

Comment: Я не говорю, что C плохой. Я говорю, что если человек изучает C, а потом переходит на C++, он продолжает писать в стиле C. Некоторые вещи из C в C++ не нужны, так как там есть более хорошая замена. Человек, переходящий с C будет писать так, как привык. Это похоже на то, что C++ - это постинкремент C, то есть C++ используется как C.

Comment: Не знаю какой именно человек имеется в виду (наверное среднестатистический), но если ему внятно объяснить, что не следует в си++ использовать например дефайны вместо констант и принтфы вместо каутов, то никаких проблем с освоением с++ после си не будет.

Comment: Почему все минусуют-то? Я ответил на вопрос и расписал по этапам изучение языка: сначала сам язык, потом практика с использованием какой-нибудь библиотеки, чтобы лучше понять язык и чтобы было интереснее (консольное окно уже может надоесть). Одной книги по языку будет недостаточно, если не знаешь хорошо другой похожий язык.